# Algorithm to compute similarity of two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, similarity

Is there any text similarity algorithm in javascript? I want to compare too essays to determine how similar they are. I was thinking about edit distance, but I don't know how to translate it into percentage.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib), a javascript implementation of python's SequenceMatcher. You can get the similar percentage:
difflib.ratio(string1, string2) * 100. Here is the [demo](http://www.textsimilarity.net/). Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!

In PHP, there's a convenient inbuilt string comparison function called `levenshtein` based on the (widely adopted) algorithm Levenshtein. In JavaScript, it isn't builtin, but it can be easily programmed, and has been.

Here is an implementation of the Levenshtein distance metric:

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/

Comment: Duly noted @Qantas94Heavy. I had no idea, because many new users don't.